# Laravel Eloquent relationship fetching third table/relation value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-5.8

I have 3 tables in a database

1. Transaction `{'id','bill_id','remark'}`
2. Bills `{'id','third_party','amount'}`
3. ThirdParty `{'id','company_name',remark}`

The **'transaction'** table has column `bill_id` coming from **'Bills'** and Bills table has `'third_party'` column which connected to ThirdParty table **column -> 'id'**

So here I am trying to fetch `company_name` using laravel eloquent relation

My **Transaction** model:

```
public function Bills()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Bills','id','bill_id');
}
```

**Bills:**

```
public function third_party()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ThirdParty','third_party','id');
}
```

I am getting **null** value for `company_name`

[image]

Here is the query i am using

```
Transaction::with('Bills.third_party')->get();
```

And i have corrected in question (third_party_name) to company_name column name i wrote here was my old join query name which is visible in screenshot, basically i am trying to fetch company name.

Comment: I don't use *Laravel* but I don't see any foreign keys in there, or at least nothing that looks like one to me.  For #3  How does that table relate to the other 2?  forgot the quotes on the last one `{'id','company_name',remark}` - just saying.

Comment: in Bills table column name third_party is foreign key which belongs to ThirdParty table primary key 'id'

Comment: show eloquent query for same

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to show all of your code? How does company_name get set to third_party_name?

You could probably also gain a lot by sticking to the laravel "conventions" or "suggested naming", this will give you a lot of functionality for free, and make your code easier to read, write and debug.

eg. Your relationship method names (Bills(), third_party()), but more importantly if you name your table fields in the "laravel way", you will get easier eloquent relationships as there will be no need to define the foreign keys etc.

I would be setting this up similar to:

1. Transaction {'id','bill_id','remark'}
2. Bills {'id','third_party_id','amount'} <- note the third_party_id
3. ThirdParty {'id','company_name',remark}

   ```
   class Transaction extends Model
   {
       public function Bills()
       {
           return $this->hasOne('App\Bills');
       }
   }

   class Bills extends Model
   {
       public function ThirdParty()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\ThirdParty);
       }
   }
   ```

You should also define the inverse relationships.

It would be very beneficial to see the full code to see where the issue is.

Comment: i have updated eloquent query, query result is returning to view as json encoded response.